# Bottling from a jockey box?

Tags: bottling, kegging, force-carbonation

So I've kegged my last batch, was an 'imperial IPA', and will drink it in my house with some few friends. It's a borrowed 19L cornelius keg, and I think that we cannot drain it completely. Since I've to give it back to the owner I was thinking about fill some bottles. And them I've think about let my friends fill bottles when we're drinking, *directly from tap*. I will use a DIY jockey box with ~15m coil and a flow controled faucet, with 'push-back creamer' function, somewhat like [that](http://www.mybeerandwine.ie/228-thickbox_default/chrome-beer-tap-with-flow-control.jpg). I use standard crown type metal caps and my capper is like [this](http://alquimiadacerveja.com.br/image/cache/data/equipamentos/arrolhador_fechador_garrafa-800x800.jpg).

So, there is a way to do this without anything else, or I strictly need at least a thing like this [BMBF](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f35/we-no-need-no-stinking-beer-gun-24678/)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottling from a tap is always tough, as you tend to lose carbonation. That is why beer guns and counter pressure bottle fillers were made.

If you'd like to fill a bottle without one of the above items, I'd recommend using a length of 5/16" hose attached to your tap. This will allow you to fill your bottles from the bottom up (not top down) and will help reduce foam and the loss of carbonation as you fill.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, bro! I was watching some videos on youtube using things like the BMBF, some calling "Poorman Beer Gun", and other names, and it looks so simple that I have no reason for try.